# Scope of "this" in inner function (CraftyJS scene)

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I'm writing up a small game using CraftyJS. Here's what I want to write:

```
Crafty.scene('MainMap', function() {

    this.player = Crafty.e('Player');       
    this.player.move(5, 5);
    this.game_objects = [this.player];

    isOccupied: function(x, y) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.game_objects.length; i++) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    if (!this.isOccupied(5, 5)) { ... }

    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected; it's not an anonymous object, but it's a function. I have to use a different syntax, and pass in my objects, like so:

```
function isOccupied(x, y, game_objects) { ... }
// Same place as previous call to isOccupied
if (!isOccupied(x, y, this.gameObjects) { ... }
```

It's clear to me why I have to declare it as `function isOccupied` and not `isOccupied: function` (because it's inside a function, not an object) but it's not clear to me what the scope of `this` is. It doesn't get passed into the function.

Is it possible to somehow keep the objects within some non-global scope, and not need to pass them into `isOccupied`?

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the parent scope to another variable, so it will be available in your closure. Like so...

```
Crafty.scene('MainMap', function() {
    var self = this;
    this.player = Crafty.e('Player');       
    this.player.move(5, 5);
    this.game_objects = [this.player];

    function isOccupied (x, y) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.game_objects.length; i++) {
        // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `this.isOccupied = function...` or `if (isOccupied...` doing both is a bug.

Comment: I get an error that `isOccupied is not a function`. I have to declare it as `function isOccupied`. It doesn't explain the scoping, althoug you have provided a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your Crafty scene.

The colon in this part should not be there. In JavaScript, colons are only used in objects.

```
// Wrong
isOccupied: function(x, y) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.game_objects.length; i++) {
            // ...
     }
}

// Right
function isOccupied(x, y) {
   // ...
}
```

In your function, `this` refers to the global object (`window`).

EDIT:
To fix this, use `Function.prototype.bind`, like so:

```
function isOccupied(x, y) {
   // ...
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: You have provided an explanation, but no solution.

Comment: My reputation score was too low to allow me to comment

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is part of what I wanted to know, though :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research, it appears that this is a [well-known issue](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/) with the `this` keyword. It will be fixed in ECMAscript 5.

To summarize: the `this` keyword gets confused when you have more than one level of nesting:

```
obj = {
  speak: function() {
    alert(this); // obj
    inner = function() {
        alert("inner: " + this); // window
    };
  }
};
```

The work-around is to use a scope chain, by assigning a variable to `this`:

```
obj = {
  speak: function() {
    alert(this); // obj
    var that = this;
    inner = function() {
        alert("inner: " + that); // obj instead of window
    };
  }
};
```

Unfortunately for me, CraftJS has me inside a function instead of an object. To declare a sub-function, I still must specify it as `function isOccupied`:

```
Crafty.scene('MainMap', function() {
    self = this; // new
    this.player = Crafty.e('Player');       
    this.player.move(5, 5);
    this.game_objects = [this.player];

    function isOccupied(x, y) { // game_objects no longer passed in
        for (var i = 0; i < self.game_objects.length; i++) { // uses self
            // ...
        }
    }

    if (!this.isOccupied(5, 5)) { ... }

    // ...
}
```